# What is the purpose of having .hgtags

Tags: mercurial

May I know what is the purpose of having .hgtags? Can I remove it? As it is not in `.hg` folder, and seems "pollute" my actual source code directory.

https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1205

Comment: The purpose of that file is to contain a list of tags and which changeset hashes they're associated with. You should not remove it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$ hg tag --help
hg tag [-f] [-l] [-m TEXT] [-d DATE] [-u USER] [-r REV] NAME...

add one or more tags for the current or given revision

    ...

    To facilitate version control, distribution, and merging of tags,
    they are stored as a file named ".hgtags" which is managed
    similarly to other project files and can be hand-edited if
    necessary. The file '.hg/localtags' is used for local tags (not
    shared among repositories).

    ...
```

From the issue you linked:

> Mercurial currently has a very nice separation between things which are not version-controlled and things that are which this would ruin.

Because .hgtags is version-controlled, it is *not* in .hg.  Compare to .hg/hgrc (in .hg; not version-controlled) and .hgignore (not in .hg; version-controlled).